# Size two-column HTML table to only right column without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to accomplish the following using only CSS and HTML, and not use JavaScript.

I have a simple HTML table that looks like this.  Both columns contain dynamic content, but the left has a scrollable div.  I want the display height of that scrollable div to size according to the table, and have the table size be set *only* by the dynamic height of `column2`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">
            <div>
            ...
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="column2">
            <div>
            ...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the table to adjust its height according to dynamic content in `column2` only, not `column1`, so that I can have a scrollable div in `column1` that sizes to the height of the table set by `column2` automatically when the page is rendered.

I have found solutions using jQuery, but the performance is very poor when I use `height()` or `outerHeight()` to find the height of the right column and set the div inside the left column appropriately, especially when the right column contains a large number of HTML elements which are in their own scrollable divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning:

```css
table {
    position: relative;
}

td {
    background: red;
    width:200px;
}

.column1>div {
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="del.css">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">
            <div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="column2">
            <div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also available as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73b49/).

Comment: The above answer is elegant.  Good going jasssonpet.  Now I'm going to add one 'kink'.  Is there a way to get this same functionality if there are two rows on the right, and only one row on the right in the "sizing" column?  I want the top left row to be fixed, with the scrolling div in the bottom left, and only one row represented in the right column, probably with `rowspan=2`.

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle, with the table and show which one is scrollable? The general idea is that you use position:absolute to take it out of the flow, so only the other col extends the table.

Comment: I actually did get it working for all browsers except IE6.  http://jsfiddle.net/BlackCatWeb/MU4eH/.  I had to take out the 'height: 100%'. On IE tester, the scroll bar does not appear and the enclosed text goes past the bottom of the table.  Can you advise on IE6?